# How to take the fields that were not selected?

Tags: javascript, angular, html, typescript

I have a Datatable which I am working with Selects.

[image]

With the "selectable" option I create a Json with the values that I have selected, now I want to take the fields that were not selected

```
<mat-card-content>
          <data-table    
          #dataTable1                                                               
          [data]="dataTableF1"
          [columns]="headerTableF1"                                                
          [selectable]="selectedRowsF1"              
          [clickable]="clickable"                          
          [sortBy]="sortBy"                               
          [(ngModel)]="selectedRowsF1"                
          [sortOrder]="sortOrder"
          (sortChange)="sort($event)"  
          (rowSelect)="selectEventF1($event)"                           
          [ngModelOptions]= "{standalone: true}"                                                             
          [style.height.px]="400"
          [style.width.px]="610"
          [disabled]="disabled"
          > 
          </data-table> 
      </mat-card-content>
```

Comment: can't you just for loop through the all data and select whether it is selected or not?

Comment: Hi Viran Malaka, I do not have much experience with data-table management, how could you do what you tell me?